# Module not found/critical dependancy when using mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

When using mongoose with nextjs, I get a bunch of errors about missing critical depandances or modules not found.

Heres the console output:

```bash
wait  - compiling...
warn  - ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-user-agent-node/dist-cjs/is-crt-available.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws-crt' in 'C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\rove-website\node_modules\@aws-sdk\util-user-agent-node\dist-cjs'

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bson.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'bson-ext' in 'C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\rove-website\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'kerberos' in 'C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\rove-website\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd' in 'C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\rove-website\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'snappy' in 'C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\rove-website\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'snappy/package.json' in 'C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\rove-website\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws4' in 'C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\rove-website\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption' in 'C:\Users\person\Documents\GitHub\rove-website\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'
```

The data gets requested and recived just fine. The only issue is these annoying errors spamming my console. I assume they should be dealt with. I relize I could just install (most) of them, but I don't need them, adn as I said, my code works just fine.

Heres my code if you're interested:

```
import connect, { Gun } from "../../lib/mongo";
import Loading from "./loading";

export default async function Guns() {
  const data = await getData();
  if (!data) {
    return <div>error</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Loading />
      guns
      {data.map((v, i) => (
        <div key={i}>{v.ammo}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

async function getData() {
  try {
    await connect();
    const r = await Gun.find({});
    return r;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Expectation:

I'm expecting to not have any errors

Comment: I have this same problem. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: sadly no. You can manually install them, but I'm not sure if they're needed in this case, and why that error is being thrown.

Comment: Looks to me that the `guns` variable after the `<Loading />` is causing the problem.

Comment: I've made a post about some guidelines when using mongoose7 with NextJs13 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697312/import-mongoose-lib-in-api-directory-in-next-js-13-2-app-directory-gives-error/75860669#75860669 maybe that would help

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue today and banged my head over all the errors about missing modules etc. I resolved it by reversing my code changes and could not really find the root cause.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi, i think `guns {data.map((v, i) =...` is incorrect and causing the errors. Similar error as my example which also caused the same errors.

Comment: That's a pretty standard piece of code... what's the issue with it?

Comment: Hi, i tried to reproduce the problem with part of your code, but I could not. I am not sure why. In my case the issue disappeared when I removed my invalid code. I removed my comment on your code.